# Least Squares Method 2nd Derivative Negative

Tags: derivatives

I'm having an extremely hard time proving that the 2nd derivative of this equation is negative. Can someone please help me with where I might be wrong?
[image]

Comment: Seems correct to me. If you're trying to prove that we're minimizing the sum of squares, the second derivative should indeed be positive.
In my own notes, I got the same answer as you, that is that the second derivative is 

$$
\frac{d^2 Q(\beta)}{d\beta^2} = 2 \sum_i X_i^2 > 0
$$

Comment: @MattiP.Thanks, I've checked with a few people that have said the same thing. So is our professor wrong? He wanted us to prove/show it's negative...

Answer (score 1):

If for $β^\star$ holds:

$$\frac{d}{dβ}Q(β^\star)=0 \\\frac{d^2}{dβ^2}Q(β^\star)<0,$$

then $β^\star$ can't be a minimum of $Q(β)$. These are the sufficient conditions for a (local) maximum.

---

Your computation is correct. Your Professor probably made slight mistake.